# How to import csv file data in aerospike without using aerospike loader?Is there any alternative available for aerospike loader?

Tags: csv, python-3.x, import, aerospike

I want to import following csv file data in aerospike and want to fire simple select query to display data using **python as a client**

e.g

```
policyID,statecode,county,eq_site_limit,hu_site_limit,fl_site_limit,fr_site_limit,tiv_2011,tiv_2012,eq_site_deductible,hu_site_deductible,fl_site_deductible,fr_site_deductible,point_latitude,point_longitude,line,construction,point_granularity
119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,498960,498960,498960,498960,498960,792148.9,0,9979.2,0,0,30.102261,-81.711777,Residential,Masonry,1
448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1438163.57,0,0,0,0,30.063936,-81.707664,Residential,Masonry,3

  query = client.query( 'test', 'csvfile' )
  query.select( 'policyID', 'statecode' )
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use the python csv module along with Aerospike Python client:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/

And do something similar to the following:

```
    import aerospike
    import sys
    import csv

    global rec
    rec = {}
    csvfile  = open('aerospike.csv', "rb")
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rownum = 0
    for row in reader:
        # Save First Row with headers
        if rownum == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            colnum = 0
            for col in row:
                # print (rownum,header[colnum],col)
                rec[header[colnum]] = col
                colnum += 1
        rownum += 1
        # print(rownum,rec)
        if rec:
             client.put(('test', 'demo', str(rownum)), rec)
        rec = {}
    csvfile.close()
```

Note: You may need to check the size of your headers and make sure they do not exceed 14 characters.
if not you could get the following:

```
error: (21L, 'A bin name should not exceed 14 characters limit', 'src/main/conversions.c', 500)
```

Answer (score 2):

as far as I am aware there is no pre-built tool other than the loader that allows you to import CSV.  You could, perhaps, build one using the existing client tools.